# How to add NSTextAlignmentCenter in attributes?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to add NSTextAlignmentCenter to the following attribute.  How?

```
[nssWord drawInRect:CGRectMake(200, 200, 500, 200) withAttributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName : [NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial Black" size:100.0] }];
```

---

tried this... nothing but showing the text works:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:nssWord];


[string drawInRect:CGRectMake(200, 200, 500, 200)];

[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
               value:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial Black" size:100.0]
               range:NSMakeRange(0, [nssWord length])];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

[string addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
               value:paragraphStyle
               range:NSMakeRange(0, [nssWord length])];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an `NSMutableParagraphStyle`, set its `alignment` property to NSTextAlignmentCenter, and then add it to the attributes dict with `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` as the key.

Comment: I added another option... but problems

Comment: @jdl Dude. You're drawing the `string` before you've finished configuring its attributes.